# Is there a way to pass a Number as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm allocating an array of T, T extends Number inside a class. I can do it this way:

```
myClass test = new myClass(Double.class, 20);
```

Then the constructor itself:

```
myClass(Class<T> type, size)
{
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, size);
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to do it like this:

```
myClass(Number n, size)
{
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(n.getClass(), size);
}
```

But, I've tried instatiating an object with the second constructor with:

```
myClass test = new myClass(Double, 15);
```

And it doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Class names as input parameters in Java. The `Object.class` was introduced to allow the passing of "Class names"

So the answer is No, you can't pass `Number` as a parameter but you can pass `Number.class`. That is what it is for :)

** Update **

Also from you second constructor definition

```
myClass(Number n, int size)
{
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(n.getClass(), size);
}
```

It is clear the input parameter is an instance of Number or it's subclasses not the class is itself. I know it is obvious but it makes clearer why it is not possible to do what you intended

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
myClass test = new myClass( Double.class, 15 );
```

You were missing the `.class` part.

Comment: His question is can you do it with out the .class (just pass Double)

Answer (score 1):

You should also have

```
myClass(Class<T> type, int size)
```